# Error using cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow to access Media Images

Tags: image, kotlin, picasso, mediastore, database-cursor

I'm trying to access the `MediaStore.Images` file using `cursor` but it keeps giving an error .
I tried creating an `image` object containing an array of images in the device, nd load it to the screen using `Picasso` library.
i created a function to get images after permission has been checked in the `onCreate` method.

```
 private fun getAllImages(): ArrayList<Image>? {
        val images = ArrayList<Image>()

        val imagesUri =MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
        val cursor = this@MainActivity.contentResolver.query(imagesUri,
            projection, null, null, null)


        try {
            cursor!!.moveToFirst()
            do {
                val image = Image()
                image.imagePath = cursor
                    .getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA))
                image.imageName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))
                images.add(image)
            }while (cursor.moveToNext())
            cursor.close()
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e("PhotoGallery", "An error occured:$e")
            Toast.makeText(this, "An error occured : $e", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return images
    }
```

This is where i called the method in the `Main Activity`

```
checkGalleryPermission()

        phoneImages = ArrayList()
        if(phoneImages!!.isEmpty()){
            progressBar?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            phoneImages = getAllImages()
                photoRecycler?.adapter = ImageAdapter(this, phoneImages!!)
                photoRecycler?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,3)
                photoRecycler?.setHasFixedSize(true)
                progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
        }
```

But it keeps giving me this error

> Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
> 2023-08-01 01:59:22.548 18765-18765 ek.photogallery         com.secondweek.photogallery          W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
> 2023-08-01 01:59:22.837 18765-18765 PhotoGallery            com.secondweek.photogallery          E  An error occured:android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
> 2023-08-01 01:59:22.837 18765-18765 Compatibil...geReporter com.secondweek.photogallery          D  Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10303; state: ENABLED
> 2023-08-01 01:59:22.848 18765-18765 Toast                   com.secondweek.photogallery          V  show: caller = com.secondweek.photogallery.MainActivity.getAllImages:83
> 2023-08-01 01:59:22.864 18765-18765 System.err              com.secondweek.photogallery          W  android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0